# install pod swift 2

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I want to use SwiftyRSA in swift 2 when I add

```
pod 'SwiftyRSA', :git => 'git@github.com:TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA.git', :branch => 'swift-2.3'
```

to pod error

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tFID, expecting keyword_end.

 #  from /Users/sina/Desktop/dev/test/Podfile:7
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
 >  pod 'SwiftyRSA', :git => 'git@github.com:TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA.git', :branch => 'swift-2.3'  use_frameworks!
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

[gitHub link](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA)
thanks for helping

Comment: Did you write `use_frameworks!` on the same line or another one (before)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add **end** in the end of podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.3'
    install! 'cocoapods', :integrate_targets => false

    pod 'SwiftLint', '0.17.0'

    target 'SwiftyRSA iOS'
    target 'SwiftyRSA watchOS'
    target 'SwiftyRSA tvOS'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy that straight from the GitHub repository readme file? If so my guess is that you might have some hidden characters that are causing issues since the format you've got there is valid. Try copying that line into a text editor and convert it to plain text.